# Magento2.4.2 Create order Programmatically not working using cronjob?

Tags: cron, magento2.4.2

Type Error occurred when creating object:

Magento\InventorySourceSelection\Model\Address, Argument 1 passed to Magento\InventorySourceSelection\Model\Address::__construct() must be of the type string, null given, called in /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121

```
<?php

namespace Mageice\Whistlapi\Command;

use Exception;
use Mageice\Whistlapi\Helper\Data;
//use Mageice\Whistlapi\Command\WorkCommand;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Mageice\Whistlapi\Api\Model\WhistlOrder;
use Mageice\Whistlapi\Api\Api;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

class ReadOrderCommand
{
   protected $settings;
   protected $api;   
   protected $objectManager;
   
    public function __construct(
        Data $settings,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        //WorkCommand $workCommand,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        Api $api,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService $orderService,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepositoryInterface,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $cartManagementInterface,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quote, 
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate $shippingRate,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order       
     ) {
          $this->settings = $settings;
        $this->eventManager = $eventManager;       
       // $this->workCommand = $workCommand;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
         $this->api = $api; 
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->orderService = $orderService;
        $this->cartRepositoryInterface = $cartRepositoryInterface;
        $this->cartManagementInterface = $cartManagementInterface;
        $this->quote = $quote;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->shippingRate = $shippingRate;
        $this->_product = $product;
$this->order = $order;      
    }


    public function createOrder($orderData) 
        {
              
            $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
            $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
            
            $customer=$this->customerFactory->create();
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
            $customer->loadbyemail('example@gmail.com');// load customet by email address
            //check the customer
            if(!$customer->getEntityId()){
                //If not avilable then create this customer
                $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                    ->setStore($store)
                    ->setFirstname($orderData['shippingAddress']['firstName'])
                    ->setLastname($orderData['shippingAddress']['lastName'])
                    ->setemail('example@gmail.com')
                    ->setPassword('Test@123');
                $customer->save();
            }
             $quote=$this->quote->create(); //Create object of quote
            $quote->setStore($store); //set store for which you create quote
           
            $customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
            $quote->setCurrency();
            $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer
            
            
     
            //add items in quote
           
            $shipping  = [
            'shipping_address' =>
                ['firstname' => $orderData['shippingAddress']['firstName'],
                'lastname' => $orderData['shippingAddress']['lastName'],
                'street' => '4 Stroude Road',
                'city' => 'Sinclairston',
                'country_id' => 'GB',
                'region' => '',
                'postcode' => 'KA18 9YP',
                'telephone' => '07533229190',
                'fax' => '',
                'save_in_address_book' => 1],
            'items'=>
                    [
                      
                        [
                            'product_id' => '24',
                            'qty' => 2,
                            'super_attribute' => [
                                93 => 272
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
            ];
            
            foreach($shipping['items'] as $item){
                $product=$this->productRepository->getById($item['product_id']);
                if(!empty($item['super_attribute']) ) {
                    / this is for configurable product /
                    $buyRequest = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($item);
                    $quote->addProduct($product,$buyRequest);
                } else {
                    / this is for simple product /
                    $quote->addProduct($product,intval($item['qty']));
                }
            }
            
              $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($shipping['shipping_address']);
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($shipping['shipping_address']);
            
            $shippingAddress=$quote->getShippingAddress();
            $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                            ->collectShippingRates()
                            ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping'); //shipping method
            $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //payment method
            $quote->setInventoryProcessed(true); //not effetc inventory
            $quote->setIsSuperMode(true);
            $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready
     
            // Set Sales Order Payment
            $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);
     
            // Collect Totals & Save Quote
            $quote->collectTotals()->save();
            
     
            // Create Order From Quote
            $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);
            
            $increment_id = $order->getIncrementId();
            }}
```

Comment: share the code of above place.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya please check my above code

Comment: Where is your class constructor of above code? please share the complete code.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya please check my full file code

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the EnvironmentEmulation class

```
public function __construct(
\Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $emulation
 ) {
$this->emulation = $emulation;
}
$storeId = 1;
$this->emulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, 'frontend');
/* Your create order code */
$this->emulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
```

This will let you access admin functions to create the order.

Comment: This code may be used admin order but i have use frontend order

Comment: Change the Environment to 'frontend'. Also, if the order is created by cronjob. It should make no difference if it's frontend of adminhtml placing the order